# JList.getSelectedValue().toString() returning null?

Tags: java, user-interface, nullpointerexception, jlist

I have a jlist that holds a bunch of username strings. I dont have a lot of experience with this, so here is the code making jlist:

```
for (int i = 0; i < usersArray.length; i++) {//usersArray is String[] loaded from a list of username strings
    defaultListModelObject.addElement(usersArray[i]);
}

jlistobject = new JList(defaultListModelObject);
```

There is a button next to the jlist, that when i click it, it calls
`System.out.println(jlistobject.getSelectedValue().toString();`

then i'm getting a nullpointerexception, that it is unable to print that value. i'm not sure what the null pointer is to, but here is the result:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at avtech.software.minecraft.server.components.UsersListPanel.getSelectedPlayer(UsersListPanel.java:56)
    at avtech.software.minecraft.server.components.PlayerCommandPanel.player(PlayerCommandPanel.java:125)
    at avtech.software.minecraft.server.components.PlayerCommandPanel.access$0(PlayerCommandPanel.java:124)
    at avtech.software.minecraft.server.components.PlayerCommandPanel$3.actionPerformed(PlayerCommandPanel.java:44)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What am I doing wrong? i'm clicking on the item in the list, and clicking this button to have it print, and it has a null pointer effect. should instead i have the value of the list item load to a string object when i click the list item?

please help!

Comment: Well presumably `getSelectedValue` is returning `null`, and you're calling `toString()` on the null reference...

Comment: If there is nothing selected, then `getSelectedValue` will return `null`.  Make sure you're not shadowing your variables and the reference to `jlistobject` you are accessing is the same as the one on the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for [`JList.getSelectedValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue%28%29) (emphasis mine):

> Returns the value for the smallest selected cell index; the selected value when only a single item is selected in the list. When multiple items are selected, it is simply the value for the smallest selected index. **Returns null if there is no selection.**

So if `getSelectedValue()` is returning `null`, you're calling `toString()` on a null reference, hence the exception.

The `toString()` call is unnecessary anyway - just use:

```
System.out.println(jlistobject.getSelectedValue());
```

... that will handle `null` references fine, and call `toString()` where necessary.

EDIT: If you really think the list has a selected value, changing to the above code will still help to make diagnosis easier. You can also use:

```
System.out.println(jlistobject.getSelectedIndex());
```

... if that prints out -1, it confirms that there's no selection. (Maybe you've actually got two separate `JList` objects without realizing it, and the one you're selecting from isn't the same as the one you're checking, for example...)

Comment: yeah wow thanks for that, but if you had finished reading my question, i clearly stated that i select an item, and click the button. SELECT

Comment: ok, but the .getSelectedValue() returns an Object, not a string. so it's either add a cast to the value, or .toString(), both doing the same thing right?

Comment: @PulsePanda: Well that suggests that at the point at which you're logging, there's probably no selection - or the selected value itself is somehow null. My guess is that the selection part isn't working properly (e.g. you're not selecting from the list you think you are), but if you *first* get rid of the exception (as per the answer) it'll help you to diagnose the rest. Use `getSelectedIndex()` for another way of checking the selection.

Comment: @PulsePanda: No, `System.out.println(Object)` is a perfectly good overload.

Comment: alright, i put it as a simple `System.out.println(list.getSelectedIndex());` which prints null. the return for getSelectedIndex() is -1.... and i have NO clue why that would be

Comment: @PulsePanda: I suspect you mean `getSelectedValue()` in that first call, not `getSelectedIndex()`. But assuming that - you need to investigate why the selection isn't in the list you think it is. We don't have even *slightly* enough context to help you with that... I suggest you look closely at your code again, and shorten it to something like can post as a complete (but short!) program in a new question. (The reason for the NullPointerException - the cause of this question - has been answered.)

Comment: @PulsePanda Did you resolve your problem? I am having the same problem. I don't know how can I trace the JList if it has a separate one.